# How does Apple Pay work when used with Family Sharing?

Tags: ios, family-sharing, apple-pay

Is it possible to use Apple Pay alongside Family Sharing? Is Apple Pay restricted to just the family organizer, or can everyone in the Family Group use their own Apple Pay accounts individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple Pay is separate to Family Sharing. Each person maintains their own Apple Pay cards and being part of Family Sharing has no effect on this. It's just like not being part of Family Sharing.